# Casio Exilim EX-Z85 camera broken flash

Tags: flash, repair, diy

Hello I have Casio Exilim EX-Z85 with broken flash lamp, does anyboy know what is the lamp size? I want to replace this lamp, I found few on the web: http://goo.gl/SUPvR (link to google translate page) but I'm not sure what is the original lamp size.

Camera specifications: http://www.letsgodigital.org/en/camera/specification/1946/show.html

Regards, Chris

Comment: You mean the flash bulb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called the "High Intensity Discharge (HID) Lamp". Parts are available in most local camera shops and they are not that costly. So consult your nearest camera repair shop and have it replaced with a compatible HID flash lamp.

take care